# Endpoint duplicate in url when I reload my page - Angular

Tags: angular

Guy do you know why angular duplicate my home endpoint when I reload the page.

When I load my page for the first time all is right, the home endpoint is set in the URL, but when I reload the page in the url is added another /home.

****before reload the page:**** http://localhost:4200/home

****after reload the page:**** http://localhost:4200/home/home

**this is my appRoutes**

```
import { Route } from "@angular/router";

export const AppRoutes:Route[] = [
    {
        path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path:'home', loadChildren: ()=> import("./modules/home/home.module").then(m=>m.HomeModule)
    }
]
```

I import this file in my appModule

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
```

**And this my Home route file**

```
import { Route } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

export const HomeRoutes:Route[] = [
    {
        path:'',
        component:HomeComponent
    }
]
```

I import this file in my HomeModule

```
RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In **index.html** add `<base href="/">` instead of `<base href="">` if its not there.
2. If it doesn't help, try turning on route tracing and debug.

   RouterModule.forRoot(
   AppRoutes,
   { enableTracing: true } // <-- For debugging purpose only
   )

Answer (score 0):

your routing configuration is correct.

this link in below is created in stackblitz base on your config.

[click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntck6o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html)

you have to find your problem some where else.